# java : ClassCastException while receiving list of objects using JPA

Tags: java, list, jpa

I'm trying to receive a list of objects of type `Tempfiles` and I'm not sure what has gone wrong in the way of fetching it. and when I receive the list, the size of the list is not zero but when I try to use it, I'm getting a ClassCastException : 
Here's the pojo of the class `Tempfiles` :

```
@Entity
@Table(name="tempfiles")
@NamedQuery(name="Tempfile.findAll", query="SELECT t FROM Tempfile t")
public class Tempfile implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer tempfilesid;

    private byte[] filestream;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Filemetadata
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="documentid")
    private Filemetadata filemetadata;

    public Tempfile() {
    }

    public Integer getTempfilesid() {
        return this.tempfilesid;
    }

    public void setTempfilesid(Integer tempfilesid) {
        this.tempfilesid = tempfilesid;
    }

    public byte[] getFilestream() {
        return this.filestream;
    }

    public void setFilestream(byte[] filestream) {
        this.filestream = filestream;
    }

    public Filemetadata getFilemetadata() {
        return this.filemetadata;
    }

    public void setFilemetadata(Filemetadata filemetadata) {
        this.filemetadata = filemetadata;
    }
}
```

Here's the method that I use to :

```
public List getTempFileData()
    {
        String METHOD_NAME = "getTempFileData";
        logger.logEntering(METHOD_NAME);
        String strQueryToGetStream = "select t.tempfilesid, t.filemetadata.documentid, t.filestream from Tempfile t";
        logger.logInfo(strQueryToGetStream);
        Query query = entityManager.createQuery(strQueryToGetStream);
        List <Tempfile>tempFileList = query.getResultList();
        logger.logExiting(METHOD_NAME);
        return tempFileList;
    }
```

Here's how I receive it :

```
List <Tempfile>tempFileList = fileDao.getTempFileData();
```

And I get the exception when I use the list in a loop :

```
for(Tempfile tempFile : tempFileList)
{
    decryptAndEncryptStream(tempFile, job, publicKey);
}
```

And this is the exception I'm getting :

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to com.global.empris.domain.Tempfile
```

Would greatly appreciate your help and thanks in advance.

Comment: Reading of any JPA docs would reveal that when you specify a SELECT clause selecting fields of the candidate then your return type is `List<Object[]>`.

Answer (score 1):

Your query is returning a list of `Object[]` instead of `TempFile`. You are only choosing specific columns, so it won't be mapped to the full object.

Process each `Object[]` like you would a resultset, or change your query to select a full object (i.e. `SELECT t FROM Tempfile t`).

Comment: Thanks for the response and ya initially I casted the list of Object[] to type TempFile. That wouldn't work too is it?

Comment: Of course it wouldn't work. Casting isn't magic transformation. Either query the full object and handle that, or query specific columns and handle those. Depending on your needs.

Answer (score 0):

IMO, you're getting an array of objects from JPA, because you only selected a portion of your entity. If you want your entity, select it and fetch its children collections like so

```
select t from Tempfile t left join fetch t.filestream
```

Comment: As I remember (might be a little rusty), you don't need to add the `select t` when only 1 entire entity is selected... Might be wrong

Comment: Well MB then, it is true that I'm more used to Hibernate than full JPA... correcting the JPQL right now

Answer (score 0):

The statement `List <Tempfile>tempFileList = query.getResultList();` returns a `List<Object>`. You should us `Transformers.aliasToBean(TempFile.class)`